# Converting an ArrayList<HashMap> into a multidimensional List

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of HashMap elements that has a format of Category, Activity and Time.  I.E.

```
{CATEGORY=Planning, ACTIVITY=Bills, TIME=5}
{CATEGORY=Planning, ACTIVITY=Bills, TIME=7}
{CATEGORY=Planning, ACTIVITY=Meetings, TIME=10}
{CATEGORY=Resources, ACTIVITY=Room1, TIME=15}
....
```

*Take note of the CATEGORY/ACTIVITY pair that is repeated as that can happen in the List*

I need to be able to convert this List into a multidimensional one.  The best way I can think of for how this List needs to look is by writing some pseudocode...please see that at the bottom of the post.

I've thought of several different approaches on how to implement this but I'm quite frankly stuck and frustrated at how to do this.  I've thought of taking the inefficient approach of looping through the ArrayList several times in outer and inner loops but I know that wouldn't be good coding practice.

Any suggestions on how I can implement this conversion so I can loop like in the pseudocode below?

```
For CATEGORY in CATEGORIES {
    CategoryTime = 0
    Display Category Header
    For ACTIVITY in ACTIVITIES {
        Activity Time = 0
        For TIME_RECORD in ACTIVITY
            Add time to activity total time, category total time & grand total
        }
        Display Activity Total
    }
    Display Category Total
}
Display Grand Total and rest of information...
```

**Edit**
I appreciate all the feedback given for this problem and it appears that really the best way to go is to enhance a class that the ArrayList of HashMap elements is a member of.

I've put in a vote to close this question as has another person as it's too localized.  I would appreciate it if some of you other developers would follow suit to close the question.  I would delete it but I can't at this point because there are answers to the question.

Comment: My off the cuff suggestion - instead of trying to make a multi dimensional list, make some classes and use them...

Comment: Yeah.  This screams out for a class with `category`, `activity`, and `time` fields.

Comment: @corsiKa - I've thought of doing that as well, but I'd like to think that this could be realized just using the Collections API without having to make custom classes...

Comment: @ZackMacomber Then Java is not for you man! JAVA is OBJECT oriented. If you don't want to design using objects, use another programming language

Comment: That generally isn't how OO languages work Zack

Comment: @AdelBoutros - why reinvent the wheel?  If I can accomplish this using the Collections API objects directly, I would like to go that route instead of writing something that has already been done...I'm just not well versed enough in Collections yet to see it in this way and I'm hoping there's someone here that might have already trod down this path...

Comment: You can accomplish this using the Collections API insofar that you have Collection OBJECTS.

Comment: It's not reinventing any wheel; it's providing a better abstraction for yourself and your clients.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Isn't an ArrayList<HashMap> a Collection Object or am I missing something here?

Comment: Also, how did "Planner" get into this post?  I'm kind of getting thrown off by that word.  I just have categories, activities and times...

Comment: Yes an ArrayList is a Collection, the CollectionS api is something different than the Collection (no S) api.  I called my class a Planner because that is what it seems like to me.  As in you plan activities based on categories that last an amount of time.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - I see what you're saying - sorry about not noticing that...

Comment: @ZackMacomber And if one day you want to do something more complexe? you come back here asking? I say again JAVA is Object Oriented not LAZY developers oriented :)

Comment: @AdelBoutros - I'm not sure how you got the impression I wanted to NOT go an OOP route with this problem.  My pseudocode is based off of looping over Objects from the Collection API.  I firmly believe and embrace modular OOP development.

Comment: "....but I'd like to think that this could be realized just using the Collections API without having to make custom classes...." - sorry, but I don't think these are the words of a person who firmly believes in and embraces OOP development.

Comment: @duffymo You cannot argue with someone who thinks creating a class and looping over it is harder then looping over a complexe collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a class that looks like so:

```
public class Planner  
{    
   Map<Category, Collection<Planner>  details;  
   String activity;  
   long time;  

}  

public enum Category  
{  
    PLANNING,RESOURCES,ETC;  
}
```

Then you should be able to do the following:

```
for(Category current: Planner.getDetails().keySet())  
{  
    CategoryTime = 0  
    Display Category Header
    Activity Time = 0
    for(Planner currentPlanner : planner.getDetails().get(current))  
    {  
          currentPlanner.getActivity();  
          Activity Time += currentPlanner.getTime();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Excuse my misunderstanding, but what's the deal with "Planner" here?  My post mentions nothing about a "Planner".  I have "Planning" activities...sorry, just getting thrown off by "Planner"...

Comment: @ZackMacomber Looks like a Planner to me.  It has a category, an activitiy, and a time.  Did you ever use Outlook the calendar planning piece?  It sounds like a primitive version of that.

Comment: OK - got ya.  The business problem I'm attempting to solve does have a little bit to do with planning...it's actually for bills in particular...

Comment: For some reason, I was thinking I could use just Collection Objects to be able to convert the ArrayList<HashMap> into List Objects but doesn't look like it from what I've seen so far...nice example and I'll be doing something similar to this in a Util class that will be responsible for converting the HashMap into a displayable format...

Answer (score 2):

The problem you'll have with using the Collections API, besides a poor abstraction, is that you'll have to store many `Activities` for a given `Category`.  If `Category` is the key, then you're forced to have a `List<Activity>` as the value in the `Map`.  And if you query for a given `Category`, your work isn't done: you have to iterate over the `List<Activity>` to find the one you want.  How will you know?

It's not a `Map`; it's a multi-map.

I agree with the folks who recommend a class.  It's far better, and not that much more work.  Better abstractions and more information hiding are usually better for you and your clients.

```
public class Activity {
    private Category category;
    private Duration duration; // You want to encapsulate value and units together, right?
    // I can see sequencing information that could be useful.  Your whole Planner seems to be in need of work.
}
```

I think your idea of time units is poorly done, too.  I can't tell if TIME=10 means 10 hours, days, weeks, months, years, decades - you get the point.  Units matter a lot, especially in this context.  You would not want people to add times together that used different units.

Comment: As I commented to Woot4Moo, what's the deal with "Planner"?

Comment: Nobody's thrown off but you.  You're changing the subject.

Comment: Did I suggest anyone else was thrown off but me?  I agree that I am indeed thrown off and that's why I posted here...

Comment: @Zack I can't speak for duffy or woot, but it appears Planner is an abstraction that allows you to group your planning activities together. If I might be so bold, I think there's a serious problem with your question: You're talking about lists and maps and all that jazz, but perhaps you should be talking about the business side of things - what your goals are in business terms, not in technical terms. Even though we're technical people, we don't do techy things for the sake of techy things, but rather to fulfil business needs. That's where our focus should be.

Comment: @corsiKa - good points, thank you.  The business side of what I'm trying to accomplish is based off of the pseudocode I listed.  I'm ultimately just trying to write a report that shows a category header, activities and times associated with that category, a category total <repeat previous items for other categories> and ultimately a grand total.